# five wires on light fixture

Tags: electrical

We're trying to install a simple new LED light fixture. The ceiling has the normal three wires but the fixture has five with the two extra being purple and silver.  What are they for? There is no dimmer function. The model is CPANL LED flat panel light fixture.

Comment: Purple & Gray are the standard colors for low-voltage dimming control. Can you give us more info on this fixture?

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the fixture and its labeling?